# Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException Laravel 4.1

Tags: php, laravel

SOLVED!!
Just add

HomeController

```
public function whereDidYouSeePost() {
    return View::make("WDS");
}
```

and Route

```
Route::post("whereDidYouSee", array(
    "as"   => "whereDidYouSee",
    "uses" => "HomeController@whereDidYouSeePost"
));
```

I am trying to post a form but everytime getting this error:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
```

But when I change the root and copy the form on my home file (I mean ../public) everything works great. What am I suppose to do?

Thank you.

Here are my codes

HomeController

```
public function whereDidYouSee() {
    return View::make("WDS");
}
```

Routes

```
Route::get("whereDidYouSee", array(
    "as"   => "whereDidYouSee",
    "uses" => "HomeController@whereDidYouSee"
));
```

Form

```
{{ Form::open(array("action" => "HomeController@WDS", "url" => "whereDidYouSee" )) }}
   //bla bla bla
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your form URL is relative, generate it based on the route name like:

```
{{  Form::open(array('route' => 'whereDidYouSee')) }}
   //bla bla bla
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: it is a solution, too but I added a post method in my HomeController file. Thank you.